# While installing ruby 2.4.10 getting Error running '__rvm_make -j8'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

Please help me to install ruby 2.4.10 command used by me:

```
rvm install ruby-2.4.10
```

When I try to install **ruby 2.4.10** in **macOS** getting following error:

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j8',
please read /usr/local/rvm/log/1692528113_ruby-2.4.10/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Here is the log from **make.log** file

```
../.././include/ruby/ruby.h:1753:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././include/ruby/ruby.h:1743:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    }
    ^
closure.c:136:29: note: ')' token is here
    ret = rb_funcall2(self, rb_intern("call"), argc, RARRAY_CONST_PTR(params));
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././include/ruby/ruby.h:1753:56: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                                                       ^
closure.c:263:14: error: call to undeclared function 'ffi_prep_closure'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    result = ffi_prep_closure(pcl, cif, callback, (void *)self);
             ^
6 warnings and 1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [closure.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/fiddle/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
++ return 2
```

Please help me to install ruby 2.4.10
command used by me: **rvm install ruby-2.4.10**

Comment: If you run `rvm get stable` then try again does it work?  This command updates your version of rvm.

Comment: Do you have `libffi` installed? `brew install libffi`

Comment: @smathy yes, I tried `brew install libffi` but still getting same error

Comment: @trinculo I used `rvm get stable` but issue still persist. my rvm is `rvm 1.29.12 (latest)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for future reference, if someone is facing something similar with rvm just uninstall `openssl@3` using brew and instead install `openssl@1.1`

1. `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl@3`
2. `brew install openssl@1.1`
3. `` rvm reinstall "ruby-2.4.10" --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl@1.1` --disable-binary ``